# How to set up htaccess and htpasswd in my private server?

Tags: .htaccess, authentication, basic-authentication, .htpasswd

At the moment I'm trying set up authentication on my test server.

The following is the list of files in the folder I'm trying to set up authentication for.

```
sftp://it@192.168.0.157/var/www/secret/.htpasswd
sftp://it@192.168.0.157/var/www/secret/.htaccess
sftp://it@192.168.0.157/var/www/secret/index.html
```

Here's what .htaccess contains:

```
AuthName "Restricted Area"
AuthType Basic 
AuthUserFile /secret/.htpasswd 
AuthGroupFile /dev/null 
<Files test.html>
require valid-user
</Files>
```

I'm not getting the login pop up. It simply shows the index.html when I go to 192.168.0.157/secret

What am I not doing correctly?

Oh btw, please ignore the fact that I haven't placed the htpasswd file in a more secure location. I just want to get this to work once and be able to demonstrate it.

Comment: I have very little experience with .htaccess password protection, but my first thought would be to try taking out the <files test.html> and matching closing tag. And then make sure the htaccess file is in directory *above* the pages you want protected

Comment: Thanks for pointing those out. I changed the name of the file I wanted to protect and forgot to edit in htaccess. Also, the problem was that my htaccess wasn't being read. After I did more research, I had to change something on the server before it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have stated URLs to a FTP server, not to the Apache web server.
When trying to access webserver, url will be: `http://192.168.0.157/secret/index.html`

In `.htaccess` you have stated that access should be controller only for `test.html`

Use this .htaccess for controlling access to all files:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted Area"
AuthUserFile /secret/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```